# Calculate a score based on a range of values

Tags: scoring-algorithm

I need to convert values to a score in points. Values can range from 0 to 15000.

What formula should I use to calculate the following?

- Any value between 0 and 50 should get the maximum score of 1000.
- Any value equal or greater than 3000 should get the minimum score of 0.
- A value of 51 should be 999 points.
- A value of 2999 should be 1 point.

The score should be an integer in the range of 0 to 1000, based on the value. Obviously, multiple different values will produce the same score.

I did some research but I am not even sure how to call what I am searching for and therefore haven't found any useful info so far.

Comment: Would not a [piecewise defined function work?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise). Also there is a lot of ambiguity on how the score should be calculated in the range $52\leq x \leq 2998$ as for example $$\text{Score}(x)=\begin{cases}1000, &0\leq x \leq 50\\ 999, & x=51\\ 1, &x=2999 \\ 0, &3000\leq x\leq 15000\\ 40, &52\leq x \leq 2998\end{cases}$$ satisfies your written requirements but I doubt it is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:
$$s = \lceil 999 - \frac{999}{2949}(v-51) \rceil$$

where the $\lceil \ \rceil$ means you round the result upwards to the next integer. If the result is larger than $1000$, you change it to $1000$, and similarly you replace any score below $0$ by $0$.

For example, $v=50$ gives $s=\lceil 999+\frac{999}{2949}\rceil = 1000$, and $v=51$ gives $s=\lceil 999\rceil = 999 $ where no rounding needed.

On the other end, $v=3000$ gives $s=\lceil 999-\frac{999}{2949}2949\rceil = \lceil 0 \rceil = 0$ exactly, while $v=2999$ gives a score of $s=\lceil  999-\frac{999}{2949}2948\rceil = \lceil 0.338 \rceil = 1$.

Comment: Brilliant! That seems to work as expected. Thanks a lot!